# How to move "Add new comment" link

Tags: nodes, comments, entities

How would I go about moving the "Add new comment" link above certain items in my content type display? Here's an example: http://www.jcpenney.com/women/fall-trend-shop/boyfriend/ana-boyfriend-cardigan-/prod.jump?ppId=pp5002961049&catId=cat100300005&subcatId=cat100250027&deptId=dept20000013&dimCombo=null&dimComboVal=null&colorizedImg=DP0705201317172824M.tif

In the link above you'll see the "write a review" link. This is where I want to place the "Add new comment" link.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the node template for your content type. You can review the [template suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) link for reference.

You can add below code in your template file to generate a link for the comments.

```
print render($content['links']['comment']);
```

Kindly see that you need to uncheck 'Show reply form on the same page as comments ' checkbox in the comment settings for your content type.